# awk replace string with another with new lines ( one time ) after finding another string

Tags: awk, sed

I wanted replace `___SIGNATURE___` with an HTML code signature after the first occurrence of "text/html" and only one replacement string `___SIGNATURE___`. Any remaining `___SIGNATURE___` tags should simply be removed.

I am processing an email message where the header has a multipart boundary so there are two body parts, one with `text/plain` and another with `text/html` and the `___SIGNATURE___` tag exists in both.

So my part of my script looks like this:

```
awk -v signature="$(cat $disclaimer_file)" '/text\/html/ {html=1;} html==1 && !swap(swap=sub(/___SIGNATURE___/, signature);}1 in.$$ > temp.mail && mv temp.mail in.$$
sed -i "s/charset=us-ascii/charset=utf-8/1;s/___SIGNATURE___//" in.$$
```

It works, but is that optimal solution?

I have used altermime before but it was not good solution for my case.

Comment: Very important thing. If someone have problem with DKIM modyfing in.$$ file like that:  dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify). This problem involves files saved on Windows. Solution: dos2unix your_signature.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to sample messages, it's hard to predict what exactly will work, and whether we need to properly parse the MIME structures or if we can just blindly treat the message as text.

In the latter case, refactoring to something like

```
awk 'NR==FNR { signature = signature ORS $0; next }
    { sub(/charset="?[Uu][Ss]-[Aa][Ss][Cc][Ii][Ii]"?/, "charset=\"utf-8\"") }
    /text\/html/ { html = 1 }
    /text\/plain/ { html = 0 }
    /___SIGNATURE___/ {
        if (html && signature) {
            # substr because there is a ORS before the text
            sub(/___SIGNATURE___/, substr(signature, 2))
            signature = ""
        } else
            sub(/___SIGNATURE___/, "")
    } 1' "$disclaimer_file" "in.$$"
```

would avoid invoking both Awk and `sed` (and `cat`, and the quite pesky temporary file), where just Awk can reasonably and quite comfortably do all the work.

If you need a proper MIME parser, I would look into writing a simple Python script.  The `email` library in Python 3.6+ is quite easy to use and flexible (but avoid copy/pasting old code which uses raw `MIMEMultipart` etc; you want to use the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` class).